# Need to transfer two head (h1) element value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to transfer my input having two h1 element:

My Input xml file having the two  element is available

```
<Body>
<h1>Head1</h1>
<h1>
<img src="https://tneb.com" />
</h1>
<h2>Head2</h2>
<p>Some people</p>
</Body>
```

XSLT I'm using for the whole set of the xml is:

```
<xsl:template match="Body[h1]">
         <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="h1[not(normalize-space())]">
         <topic outputclass="">
            <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2"/></xsl:attribute>
            <title outputclass="">
               <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </title>

            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="h2">

               <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="self::h2">
                     <topic outputclass="TOPIC">
                        <xsl:attribute name="id">topic_<xsl:number count="h1 | h2"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <title outputclass="Section">
                           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
                        </title>

                        <body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except ."/></body>
                     </topic>

                  </xsl:when>

                  <xsl:otherwise>
                     <body><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/></body>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
               </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>

         </topic>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
   </xsl:template>

         <xsl:template match="img"> 
       <xsl:element name="image">
            <xsl:if test="@src">
              <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@src"/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
```

Actually currently I'm getting output as:

```
<topic outputclass="" id="topic_1">
   <title outputclass="">Head1</title>
</topic>
Error on line 19 
  SEPM0004: When 'standalone' or 'doctype-system' is specified, the document must be
  well-formed; but this document contains more than one top-level element
  in built-in template rule
```

But Expected output needs to be like:

```
<topic outputclass="" id="topic_1">
   <title outputclass="">Head1</title>
   <body>
      <image href="https://tneb.com"/>
   </body>
   <topic outputclass="TOPIC" id="topic_2">
      <title outputclass="Section">Head2</title>
      <body>Some people</body>
   </topic>
</topic>
```

I need the image value, But i want to remove the second `<h1>` tag along with the `<img>` tag. Please suggest me some code by using this template. Thank You

Comment: Consider to post a minimal but complete stylesheet allowing us to easily reproduce the problem. Also add the output you currently get.

Comment: Please explain (in words) the exact rules you want to apply to the transformation.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Actually by using the same template, i can able to run the single <h1> tag types of input xml files. But while come into the two <h1> tag input files. the above error is occuring. I want to remove the <h1>of along with <img> tag. But I need the <img> values. Can you please suggest me some code. I'm using saxon-PE 9.6.0.7 and XSLT version 2.0.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start from the following dependencies between your input and desired output:

1. The source of the "external" `topic` element are (initial) `h1` elements.
   The first of them is the title and the content (children) of the others
   are the content of the `body`.
2. There is a similar dependence between "other" tags (other than `h1`).
   The first of them is the title of the "internal" `topic` element and
   the content (this time *text*) of the others are the content of the `body`.

So I created the following script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Body[h1]">
    <xsl:element name="topic">
      <xsl:attribute name="outputclass"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="id" select="'topic_1'"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="topicContent">
        <xsl:with-param name="src" select="h1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:element name="topic">
        <xsl:attribute name="outputclass" select="'TOPIC'"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="id" select="'topic_2'"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="topicContent">
          <xsl:with-param name="src" select="*[name()!='h1']"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="outClass" select="'Section'"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="copyVariant" select="2"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="topicContent">
    <xsl:param name="src"/>
    <xsl:param name="outClass" select="''"/>
    <xsl:param name="copyVariant" select="1"/>
    <xsl:element name="title">
      <xsl:attribute name="outputclass" select="$outClass"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$src[1]"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="body">
      <xsl:if test="$copyVariant = 1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="subsequence($src, 2)/*"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="$copyVariant != 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="subsequence($src, 2)"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="img">
    <xsl:element name="image">
      <xsl:attribute name="href" select="@src"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

The template matching `img` is needed to "translate" the source `img`
element into target `image` (with respective changes in attribute names).

### Edit

If you have multiple `h2` tags, then the template matching `Body[h1]`
should be as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="Body[h1]">
  <xsl:element name="topic">
    <xsl:attribute name="outputclass"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="id" select="'topic_1'"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="topicContent">
      <xsl:with-param name="src" select="h1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*[name()!='h1']" group-starting-with="h2">
      <xsl:element name="topic">
        <xsl:attribute name="outputclass" select="'TOPIC'"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="id" select="'topic_2'"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="topicContent">
          <xsl:with-param name="src" select="current-group()"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="outClass" select="'Section'"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="copyVariant" select="2"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

All elements other than `h1` should be divided into groups, each starting
with `h2` element. Then, for each such group, create a `topic` element and
inside it call the `topicContent` template, but this time the `src`
parameter should be the current group.

Comment: Its working fine @valdi_Bo. Thanks a lot. If I'm having multiple <h2> elements. How I can proceed? Please suggest